# Complement of the zero section in degree $k$ line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ over $\mathbb{P}^n$. Let $L^{-k}$ denote the total space of $\mathcal{O}(-k)$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it is claimed that the complement of the zero section in $L^{-k}$ is biholomorphic to the quotient $(\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \!-\! \{0\})/\mathbb{Z}_k$. Where $\mathbb{Z}_k = \{0, ..., k-1 \}$ acts as follows:
\begin{equation} 
z \mapsto e^{\frac{2 \pi i m}{k}}, \;\;\; m \in \mathbb{Z}_k. 
\end{equation}

I think that this will follow from considering the transition functions of $\mathcal{O}(-k)$ which with respect to the standard open cover $U_i$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ are given by:
\begin{equation}
g_{ij}(l) = \bigg(\frac{z_i}{z_j} \bigg)^k, \;\;\; l=[z_o: ... : z_n] \in \mathbb{P}^n.
\end{equation}
But I just can't come up with a concrete way to realise this biholomorphism, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is it helpful to consider the line bunle $E$ that is constructed from $g_{ij}$ in the standard way, that is, we let define the total space by:
\begin{equation} E = (U_i \times \mathbb{C})/\sim \end{equation}
where $(l,w) \sim (l, \bigg(\frac{z_i}{z_j} \bigg)^k w)$ for all $l \in U_i \cap U_j$ and $w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Intgr}{\mathbf{Z}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$Let $(z_{0}, \dots, z_{n})$ denote Cartesian coordinates on $\Cpx^{n+1}$. Over the set $U_{\alpha} = \{z_{\alpha} \neq 0\}$, use the standard affine coordinates on $\Proj^{n}$:
$$
\frac{z_{0}}{z_{\alpha}},\ \dots, \widehat{\frac{z_{\alpha}}{z_{\alpha}}},\ \dots, \frac{z_{n}}{z_{\alpha}}.
$$
Each affine coordinate is $\Intgr_{k}$-invariant, and therefore descends to the quotient $U_{\alpha}/\Intgr_{k}$. The $\Intgr_{k}$-invariant function $w_{\alpha} = z_{\alpha}^{k}$ on $U_{\alpha}$ will serve as fibre coordinate over the quotient.

The coordinate transition from $U_{\alpha}/\Intgr_{k}$ to $U_{\beta}/\Intgr_{k}$ is multiplication by $\zeta_{\alpha}^{\beta} := z_{\alpha}/z_{\beta}$, and the fibre transition function is $(\zeta_{\alpha}^{\beta})^{-k} = z_{\beta}^{k}/z_{\alpha}^{k}$, i.e., $w_{\beta} = z_{\beta}^{k}/z_{\alpha}^{k}\, w_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Sorry I am a tad confused over what you have shown here. Could you give me the idea behind this as I don't see how it shows that the total space without the zero section is biholomorphic to the desired $\mathbb{Z}_k$ quotient? I am probably being blind so sorry if it is clear!

Comment: I was deliberately being sketch-y so as not to take away all your fun. :) The idea is to form the quotient $(\Cpx^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/\Intgr_{k}$, cover this quotient with the images of the sets $U_{\alpha}$, use the indicated functions as coordinates for the total space of some line bundle $L$, and observe that the transition functions are those for $\mathscr{O}(-k)$.

Comment: ha that is fair enough, sorry I just do not have the time to think about this problem much and just wanted a quick solution so I can use the result. Clearly I have been over-complicating the issue thank you for the help!